# Re run expo dev client

Tags: expo

I have an expo app that I prebuild to install some native dependencies, then one of the dependencies wont work with expo GO so now I did `npx expo run:android -d` and installed the dev client on phone made changes that reflected on the fly and was happy
So now it is a new day and i want to continue working on my app. The phone is connected via usb to my computer and i tried doing  `npx expo start --dev-client` when i scan the QR code nothing happens.
How do i resume where i left the previous day? What steps did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me.
`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`